# Pattern for passing common data to _layout.cshtml in MVC4.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to come up with the best pattern for passing data to my _layout.cshtml page.

I am toying with creating a common base class from which all view specific models derive.  This base class would be recognized by my _layout.cshtml and used to fill in details about the user and load proper images in the header, etc.  For example, here is a snippet of it.

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```

At the top of my _layout.cshtml I have...

```
@model MyProject.Web.Controllers.ViewModelBase
```

I need a common area to hydrate the information required by the model, and am planning to use the following pattern...

1. Each action method creates and hydrates a model derived from
   ViewModelBase.
2. The action completes.
3. I create a ActionFilterAttribute and override OnActionExecuted to cast the
   current Result to ViewModelBase.
4. If the conversion is successful, then I populate the ViewModelBase details with the relevant data.

Here are my questions...

1. Is the use of a ActionFilterAttribute (OnActionExecuted) a good pattern for what I am trying to do?
2. I am not able to see how to get the Result created in the action from the HttpActionExecutedContext.  How is this done?

Comment: A base view model will really add overhead to all of your view models during creation or population. One way to avoid that is to use the `ViewBag` populated in `OnActionExecuted` from a base controller. That will keep your view models flexible while getting the common model via base controller. However, you'd probably want to go the way of a child action to get the strongly typed model and not be restricted to the base view model. There are a few SO posts showing both methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I follow the same approach and use a base ViewModel class which all my other viewModels inherit from.

Then, I have a base controller that all controller inherit from. In there, I have one method that takes care of initializing the view model:

```
protected T CreateViewModel<T>() where T : ViewModel.BaseViewModel, new()
{
    var viewModelT = new T {
                        HeaderTitle = "Welcome to my domain",
                        VisitorUsername = this.VisitorUsername,
                        IsCurrentVisitorAuthenticated = this.IsCurrentVisitorAuthenticated,

                        //...
                    };

    return viewModelT;
}
```

Then on each controller, when I want to create the view model, I simply call the base controller's method:

```
var vm = base.CreateViewModel<MyPageCustomViewModel>();
```