# How do I check properties of the currently logged on user from the cshtml file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am making a website in visual studio using mvc. I have created a database to store users and one of the properties is a bool called IsAdmin.

I am trying to add a couple links in the navbar on the layout of the site so it is only visible to people for true in the admin fields. How would I access the user properties from the _Layout.cshtml, to see if the user does have a value of true for the IsAdmin field?

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "Account", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
<li>@Html.Action("UserNavPartial", "Account", new { area = "" })</li>
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("View Schedule", "ManageSession", "Session", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sign Up", "Index", "Session", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
   @if (@*checking if admin right here*@)
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: That really depends on what you mean when you say "I have created a database to store users".  Is this a custom database table?  Or did you use something like ASP.Net Identity?

Answer (score 0):

A common way to do this is by using a strongly-typed _Layout/master page where a `BaseViewModel` has the properties that are common to all pages (like navigation items).

Here is an example: [Pattern for passing common data to _layout.cshtml in MVC4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930919/pattern-for-passing-common-data-to-layout-cshtml-in-mvc4-5)

Answer (score 0):

This should be the line you are looking for (of course you would change the **Administrator** for the role you need).

```
@User.IsInRole("Administrator")
```

In case you are wondering how would you connect your table to the roles within the MVC this should give you a nice start.

**LoginController.cs**

Let's say you have a Login controller with an action which you use authenticate user. As soon as you authenticate the user user the following line:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(client.Usernam, false);
```

**Global.asax**

After you have authenticated the user you would need the following method in the Global.asax file.

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported == true)
    {
        if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
        {
            try
            {           
                string username = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).Name;
                string roles = string.Empty;

                using (Entities db = new Entities())
                {
                    Client client = db.Client.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Username== username);

                    if (client.isAdmin)
                    {
                        roles = "Administrator;User";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        roles = "User";
                    }
                }
                HttpContext.Current.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(
                  new System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity(username, "Forms"), roles.Split(';'));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had posted this and deleted it.. I don't think he is using the roles table that is baked into MVC. Sounds custom. Like he needs to strongly pass a model to the view and look for Model.isAdmin == true

Comment: @mwwallace8 True, could be that he is using something else. However, I've edited the post to make it easier to get the grip.

Answer (score 0):

One way is

In Model:

```
namespace mvc.Models
{
    public static class StaticClass
    {
        public static bool IsAdmin
        {
            get { return (bool)HttpContext.Current.Session["IsAdmin "]; }
            set { HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("IsAdmin ", value); }
        }
    }
}
```

In View

```
@if(mvc.Models.StaticClass.IsAdmin)
{
    <label>True</label>
}
```

After Login by Admin, set session:

```
        Models.StaticClass.IsAdmin = true or false based on logged in user to get it in view;
```